# How do I do something like Google Map's introduction callout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface, android-fragments

When opening Google Maps' Drawer menu for the first time, or with cleared app storage you will get a view like this:

[image: Introduction Image]

The normal view is typically like this:

[image: Normal View]

I've been messing around in my XMLs for a while and I still can't get anything remotely similar to show up. Does anyone know how they do the selective dimming and the overlayed callout?

Comment: Hint for further searches: "onboarding"

Answer (score 0):

Try this library: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView
A bit outdated, but I used it a couple of years ago and it still works perfectly in my app.